# Windows: My User is in the "Administrators" Group. What does change when I select "Run as Adminstrator" in the Start-Menu?

Tags: windows, user-accounts

I don't know anything about Windows and try to understand the concepts about Permissions. Unfortunately, simply Googling doesn't help at all.

Windows says that my user is a member of the "Administrator" group. But yet, when I normally run programs, such as PowerShell, they reject to do certain things, such as installing new services. However when I select "Run as Administrator" in the Start-Menu, they suddenly are able to do so. What's the mechanism behind that?

I created a file within a process (PowerShell) that was "Run as Administrator" and then checked the owner of the file in Windows. But much to my surprise, the owner was my own user, instead of the "Adminstrator" user.

What's going on?

Comment: If you're familiar with *nix systems, "Run as Administrator" is the functional equivalent of SUDO.

Comment: @DanIsFiddlingByFirelight and by extension, an "administrator account" is one that's listed in the `/etc/sudoers` file as being allowed to use `sudo`?

Comment: @Barmar yes it is.

Comment: @DanIsFiddlingByFirelight having read more about this, I am now certain that it is not the equivalent to `sudo`. But more similar to `seccomp` and `capabilities` (see https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/capabilities.7.html ), because the user does not change, but rather the capabilities of the process, running with the same user, change. That's called "same-desktop elevation". In fact I previously misunderstood it to be functionally equivalent to `sudo`, which was the source of the confusion.

Comment: I believe, with my limited Windows knowledge (take with grain of salt) that the equivalent of sudo would be using `Start-Process -Credentials` while passing the credentials of an administrator user and being logged in as a non-administrator. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process?view=powershell-7.3#example-8-run-a-command-as-an-administrator-using-alternate-credentials .

Comment: We're just disagreeing on definition.  By functional equivalent I meant it's what you use to get the same function, not that the implementation details were the same.  Also unless it was removed in later versions (last time I saw it done was at prior job on w7), you can have run as admin open a prompt for an admin user/pw while logged in as an a non-admin user.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

See the Microsoft article
[Understanding User Account Control (UAC)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/sqlupdates/understanding-user-account-control-uac-a-brief-summary)
and especially the section
[Standard and Administrator Access Tokens](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/sqlupdates/understanding-user-account-control-uac-a-brief-summary#standard-and-administrator-access-tokens)
that fully explains what happens:

> **Standard and Administrator Access Tokens**
>
> 1. When an administrator logs on, the user is assigned two separate access tokens:
>
>    - a full administrator access token and a
>    - standard user access token.
> 2. The full administrator access token is not invoked until the user attempts to perform an administrative task.
>
>    - In other words, if you log on as a member of the local administrators group, you will run with your administrative privileges
>      disabled until you attempt to run an application or task that has been
>      marked to require administrative privileges. When UAC is enabled,
>      local administrator accounts run as standard user accounts until
>      elevation is required.